# How to use user defined attribute in KeepassXC autotype feature?

Tags: linux, keepass

I would like to ask about Keepass Auto-Type.

I would like to start using Additional attributes in auto type.

```
command: eval "$(ssh-agent -s)" && ssh-add

and use it in keepas like:
{COMMAND}{PASSWORD}{ENTER}
```

Can You help me in this case ?
I am using KeePassXC on Linux.

Thank You for support.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looking [at the documentation](https://keepassxc.org/docs/KeePassXC_UserGuide.html#_configure_auto_type_sequences), I assume you want something like this:

```
{S:command}{ENTER}{PASSWORD}{ENTER}
```

The `command` is case-sensitive name of the additional attribute.

Comment: `S` has to be capitalised otherwise it won't work

Answer (score 1):

good answer - insufficient documentation IMHO

### additional "attributes" a.k.a. variables in KeePassXC

if you need more additional "attributes"
a.k.a. variables to use in your vast and complicated auto-type sequences in KeePassXC:

1. define all necessary variables in the area
   Advanced Entry Options
   Additional Attributes
   Here you define key - value pairs.
2. use them whenever you like with the
   Entry Placeholder {S:<ATTRIBUTE_NAME>}   Value for the given attribute (case sensitive)

like this example placeholder:

> budgerigar       },oC2DxLWV(

Later call

> {S:budgerigar}

where you like.

It populates the value

> },oC2DxLWV(

into your GUI window.

Auto-Type Actions
So easy - why
are arbitrary parameters
and additional variables not described in the documentation?

Because we want to spend time on learning!

Have fun.